# Pandoc export HTML to Word with CSS display: none not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, pandoc

I have a `span` element in an HTML document with an inline `style="display:none"`. When I run the document through Pandoc converting to Word, the `span` content is present in the exported Word document. How can I make this `span` not show up at all in the exported document? Removing it from the page is not an option because it contains data that is used by javascript elsewhere on the page.

Comment: Have you tried adding `display: block` then setting the `height` and `width` to `0`?

Answer (score 0):

Pandoc doesn't understand CSS, only HTML/Markdown, etc. As such, your style attribute is ignored when exporting to formats other than HTML/epub.

To insert hidden data that will get through to the HTML output, you can either use a comment:

```
<!-- my data -->
```

or an empty span or div:

```
<span data-content="my data"></span>
```